# Exporting a subset of pages from a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I would like to get a subset of pages out of a PDF file. Basically I give the function a file, split it into pages and then create a new file with just the pages between the start and end page. As the users are entering the page numbers I need correct for Lists starting at 0. Here is the code I have.

```
     public static String SplitPdf(File source, Integer startPage, Integer endPage) throws Exception {

        String sourceFileName = source.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
        File file = new File(sourceFileName);

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
        List<PDDocument> pages = splitter.split(document);

        Integer correctedStartPage = startPage < 1 ? 1 : startPage - 1;
        Integer correctedEndPage = endPage < 1 ? 1 : endPage - 1;

        if (pages.size() <= correctedStartPage) throw new Exception("Start page: " + startPage + " No of pages: " + pages.size());
        if (pages.size() <= correctedEndPage) throw new Exception("End page: " + endPage + " No of pages: " + pages.size());
        if (startPage > endPage)
            throw new Exception("Start page before end page. Start page: " + startPage + " End page: " + endPage);

        PDDocument newDoc = new PDDocument();
        String filePath = file.getParent() + "\\" + FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()) + "-fittingPart" +
                "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());

        for (int i = correctedStartPage; i <= correctedEndPage; i++) {

            PDDocument currentPage = pages.get(i);
            PDPage page = currentPage.getPage(0);
            newDoc.addPage(page);
            currentPage.close();
        }

        newDoc.save(filePath);
        newDoc.close();

        return filePath;
    }
```

the error I am getting is:

COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?

I did check that the file exists

As far as I can see I am not closing the PDDocument too early... any ideas?

PS: I need to use apache PDFBox and not some other library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to close all PDDocument objects, the source object and the objects you've generated with `splitter` and not just the final object. You should also make your life easier by using the splitter methods `setStartPage()` and `setEndPage()` instead of creating all these intermediate documents and then taking the first file. Make sure you're closing the objects only after all have been saved (due to possible sharing of resources)

Comment: I tried todo that but now I am getting: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed? -> to be clear I did a load orig PDF, set start and end for splitter, split, close orig PDF. I updated the loop to just do an addPage and then saved the newDoc...

Comment: "COSStream has been closed and cannot be read" is when you're closing prematurely. Close any PDF only after all savings done.

Comment: I did close the PDDocument document once I had called the split function - I moved this to the end of the function and it is working now... not quite sure as all that I have changed is that I now set the start and end page before the split... weird. Anyway, it is working so thank you very much!